# Calculating Expectation of Exponential Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I want to simplify and get the answer for following expression:
$$E[e^{-r(t_2-t_1)}e^{\int_{t_1}^{t_2}(\mu_u-\frac{\sigma_u^2}{2})du+\sigma_udW_u}|F(t_1)]$$ Where $r$ is a constant and $W_u$ is standard Brownian motion.

Here what I tried. First I rewrote above expression as $$E[e^{\int_{t_1}^{t_2}(\mu_u-r-\frac{\sigma_u^2}{2})du+\sigma_udW_u}|F(t_1)]$$

Then I defined $$\hat{W_u}=\bigg(\frac{\mu_u-r}{\sigma_u}\bigg)u+W_u$$ which is distributed normally with mean $\bigg(\frac{\mu_u-r}{\sigma_u}\bigg)u$ and variance $\sigma_u u$.  This allows me to write expectation expression as 
$$E[e^{\int_{t_1}^{t_2}(-\frac{\sigma_u^2}{2})du+\sigma_ud\hat{W}_u}|F(t_1)]$$ Now I am stuck, since $\mu_u, \sigma_u$ are not constant.

Comment: As this is obviously the solution to $$dX_t=(μ_t-r)X_tdt+σ_tdW_t,$$ you get for the expectations $$d\Bbb{E}[X_t]=(μ_t-r)\Bbb{E}[X_t]dt.$$ This is an ordinary DE that can be solved via separation or integrating factor.

Comment: I think you meant $dX_t = (\mu_t-r)X_tdt + X_t\sigma_tdW_t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose $F(t) = \sigma(W_s,s\leq t)$. I recall that $M_t = \int_0^t\sigma_s dW_s$ is a Wienner integral. Therefore:

- $M_t \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \int_0^t\sigma_s^2ds\right)$
- for $s\leq t$, $M_t - M_s $ is independant of $F_s$

We have then :
\begin{align}
E[e^{-r(t_2-t_1)}e^{\int_{t_1}^{t_2}(\mu_u-\frac{\sigma_u^2}{2})du+\sigma_udW_u}|F(t_1)] &= e^{-r(t_2-t_1)+\int_{t_1}^{t_2}(\mu_u-\frac{\sigma_u^2}{2})du}E[e^{\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sigma_udW_u}|F(t_1)] \\
&= \exp\left\{-r(t_2-t_1)+\int_{t_1}^{t_2}(\mu_u-\frac{\sigma_u^2}{2})du + \frac12\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sigma_u^2du\right\} \\
&= \exp\left\{-r(t_2-t_1)+\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mu_udu\right\} 
\end{align}